# Rails how to extract data from nested JSON data

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I am trying to parse out the values I need from this nested JSON data. I need to get from `quotas` is `responders` and I need to get from `qualified` is `service_id`, `codes`.

I tried first to get just the `quotas` but kept getting this error `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

```
      hash = JSON::parse(response.body)
       hash.each do |data|
         p data["quotas"]
       end
```

Json data

```
{
  "id": 14706,
  "relationships" : [
    {
      "id": 538
    }
  ]
  "quotas": [
    {
      "id": 48894,
      "name": "Test",
      "responders": 6,
      "qualified": [
        {
          "service_id": 12,
          "codes": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            6,
          ]
        },
        {
          "service_id": 23,
          "pre_codes": [
            1,
            2
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to convert your example into json. Then I could loop the quotas and output the values.

```
hash = JSON::parse(data.to_json)
hash['quotas'].each do |data|
  p data["responders"]
  data["qualified"].each do |responder|
    p responder['service_id']
    p responder['codes']
  end
end
```

Hash in data variable (needed for the sample code to work):

```
require "json"

data = {
  "id": 14706,
  "relationships": [
    {
      "id": 538
    }
  ],
  "quotas": [
    {
      "id": 48894,
      "name": "Test",
      "responders": 6,
      "qualified": [
        {
          "service_id": 12,
          "codes": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            6,
          ]
        },
        {
          "service_id": 23,
          "pre_codes": [
            1,
            2
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: yes, it should be JSON. I am parsing the response from my api call. i am doing `JSON::parse(response.body)` and i get the output from listed above

Comment: Updated my answer to explain why I used to_json in my test variable.

Comment: got i got it now but can you explain why `.to_json` is different from how my output was with `JSON::parse(response.body)`

Comment: I think you looped over the resulting json with `hash.each do |data|` but quotas is in `hash['quotas']`, no loop needed here.

Comment: to_json was required for me to covert the hash, as I had no json result due to no access to the api